# Fastest way to learn fluent ENGLISH

Tags: learning-methods

What are the resources and the way to learn **fluent English** in less amount time? I mean ways like watching movies or reading novels etc.

Comment: Thanks. But i didn't get what should i do now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although your question is not about the English language *per se*, some of the best advice I've ever been given is:

**Total immersion** is usually one of the best ways of learning **any** language. It can be a **trial by fire** or a **sink or swim** scenario, but if you can survive it, it works. **Go** to a country, **speak** the language, **learn** the culture, and **communicate**.  Of course try to find **sympathetic native speakers** who will help you and hang out with them.  **Learn as a child learns** with an open mind, and ask lot of questions.  You may surprise yourself!

When you start **to dream** in your new language, then you know you are getting there.

Good luck!

Comment: I mean which way is fast i.e is watching movies? or reading novels or just hang out with friends who are fluent in English? Can u guide me

Comment: @HackChamp total immersion is the fastest way. It may not be the easiest, or the most comfortable, but hunger is a great motivator when you need to learn how to order food (for example). When a person learns a second language it is stored in a different place in your brain than your primary language. That's why if you know several languages (French and Russian) and you are looking for a French word, you might think of the Russian one, because they are all **secondary** to your native language.

Comment: You should try all the different methods you mention and see which works best for you, it will be different for each individual. There is no **silver bullet**.  It also depends how high your bar is for being **fluent**.