# English speaking

Tags: prepositions, sentence-construction, phrase-usage

What's the best way to be a fluent English speaker? Is it by meeting some English speaker or I can be good in speaking with out meeting any English speakers? And do you any smart phone application for participating English?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fastest way to learn fluent ENGLISH](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/76825/fastest-way-to-learn-fluent-english)

Comment: @JavaLatte I'm really reluctant to close questions as duplicates of other closed questions. If the duplicate should have been closed, and this is a real duplicate of the other, than this one should be closed independently for the same reason and not because it's a dupe.

Comment: @ColleenV, this question is too broad **and** it is a duplicate of a question which has an answer that was accepted by the OP.

Comment: @JavaLatte I'm not suggesting you're wrong that it's a duplicate. I just think that it's strange to say "This is to broad to answer properly" and "It already has an answer on this site." From the help center, _The fundamental goal of closing duplicate questions is to help people find the right answer by getting all of those answers in one place._  so closing as a dupe seems to me to say that there is a good answer to point someone to. I'm not that confident I have the "correct" view though, which is why I commented.

Comment: The best way to be a fluent English speaker is to surround yourself with English speakers and speak English with the them. I would advise you not to hold too much ambition for losing your accent, however, since even long time English speakers in America do not lose their native accents if they learn English after the age of 12 (give or take some years).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a TED talk video about this called ["How to learn any language in six months"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d0yGdNEWdn0) that has some great pointers. The speaker says that although total immersion is the fastest way to become fluent, immersion alone is not sufficient, and lists several other steps that help speed up the learning process. Some of them are:

1. Listen to the new language a lot, even if you don't understand meaning (yet). Pay attention to the intonations, rhythms, and patterns in the language.
2. Watch the body language of native speakers and try to understand the meaning they are trying to communicate, even before you understand the words.
3. Start by learning useful phrases: "What is this?" "What does that mean?" "How do you say?" "I don't understand." "Repeat that please". All of these phrases will help you to acquire very basic language from native speakers.
4. Then focus on learning the core words of the language. Learn the most common 1000 words.
5. Find a language parent; someone who knows the language, is interested in teaching you, and willing to understand your incorrect attempts at speaking the new language.
6. Don't create a link in your mind between words in your language and words in the new language. When you learn a new word, link it to the concept it describes. So when you learn the word for "fire" in a new language make a mental image of heat, smoke, and moving flames whenever you use the new word instead of trying to link it with the word 'fire' in your native language.